# How to initialise a nested input field with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a hierarchical list of values (id, code, name, parent_id) for which the code is the business key. This means that when a user wants to attach a value to a parent, he fills in a parent_code field, and before save the model associates the parent value id. The value.rb model has a virtual attribute: parent_code, and the following before_save action:

```
class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
extend CsvHelper

# This virtual attribute allows user to ignore parent value id
attr_accessor :parent_code

### scope
#  Value is linked to a list which belongs to the correct scope

### before filter
before_save :set_parent_id # user only inputs parent code

### validation
    validates :code, presence: true
    validates :name, presence: true

    belongs_to :values_list
    has_many :subs, :class_name => "Value", :foreign_key => :parent_id
    belongs_to :superior, :class_name => "Value", :foreign_key => :parent_id

### private functions definitions
  private

    ### before filters
    def set_parent_id
        self.level = 1
        if not self.parent_code.blank?
             @parent = Value.where("code = ? and values_list_id = ?", self.parent_code, self.values_list_id).first
             self.parent_id = @parent.id
             self.level = @parent.level.next
        end
    end
end
```

This model is used as nested object of a values_list model. This works fine at creation, and produces the expected result.

But when editing a record, the parent_code attribute is by no way initialized, and thus now shown in the input field. Here is the nested form:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
  <tr align="left">
    <th></th>
    <% if @values_list.is_hierarchical %>
      <th> <%= t('ParentCode') %> </th>
      <th> <%= t('Level') %> </th>
    <% end %>
    <th> <%= t('Code') %> </th>
    <th> <%= t('Value') %> </th>
    <th> <%= t('Description') %> </th>
  </tr>
  <%=  f.nested_fields_for :values, @values_list.values.order(:code), wrapper_tag: 'tr' do |value| %>
    <td><%= value.remove_nested_fields_link {image_tag("remove.png")} %></td>
    <% if @values_list.is_hierarchical %>
      <td><%= value.text_field :parent_code, ***# code to initialise #*** %> </td>
      <td><%= value.text_field :level, disabled: true %> </td>
    <% end %>
    <td><%= value.text_field :code %> </td>
    <td><%= value.text_field :name %> </td>
    <td><%= value.text_field :description %> </td>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

How can I initialise the input field with **myvalue.superior.code** ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to look at [how to translate ActiveRecord models](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) instead of adding a bunch of keys like `ParentCode` in the root of your translation files. Its gonna get real messy as your application grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access the form object that you're using in your `f.nested_fields_for` and set the value that way probably.

```
 <%=  f.nested_fields_for :values, @values_list.values.order(:code), wrapper_tag: 'tr' do |value| %>
   ...
      <td><%= value.text_field :parent_code, value: value.object.superior.code %> </td>
      <td><%= value.text_field :level, disabled: true %> </td>
    ...
```